# TLS Client Hello request contains unknown version in iOS or Android

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin, ssl

I have noticed that my native mobile applications for iOS and Android had stoped work due unknown reason on some providers in Russia.
My quick research with Wireshark shows me the reason of this behaviour (I was wrong - see my post update below):

[image: (blocked packet wireshark screenshot)]

if a TLS Client Hello packet contains unknown version in supported_version field, it is blocked by provider's DPI and my backend server doesn't receive it.

But at the same time when I try to make the same REST API request from JS browser or Insomnia, it works and TLS Client Hello packet don't contains any "unknown versions".

[image: (normal passed packet wireshark screenshot)]

Unknown version of TLS randomly changes every time, it may be:
0xbaba, 0xcaca, 0x1a1a and so on - any of 0x*a*a template.

I am not sure, but suspect, what this filtering is happens due Government Firewall equipment that most providers in our country start to use, because on the networks without this equipment this problem is not takes place. Therefore unfortunately I can not fix this problem on provider's side.

How can I force my Swift and Kotlin applications to not use this unknown version inside TLS protocol?

UPDATE:
It seems, unsupported version in not the reason of this behaviour.
It is also contained in packets when I open this URL in Safari on the same device.

But I've found another difference in TLS packets:

This packet is blocked (my App):
[image: Blocked packet]

This packet is passed (Safari):
[image: Passed packet]

UPDATE2:
Setting NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy=NO solved this problem.

Comment: *"My quick research with Wireshark shows me the reason of this behaviour:"* - It does not show you the reason. It shows you some differences and you pick one and **suspect** that this is the reason. But given that Grease values for TLS protocol is a widely used feature of Chrome browser I doubt that what you suspect is really the cause of the problem. Because in this case lot more would break than just your application.

Comment: Steffen Ullrich, Yes, I have already realized it.

Comment: Even your update points to a widely used feature - the client announcing support for HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2. I very much doubt that this is the reason either. Also - don't make your question a moving target: you had one question on how to remove the "unknown version". Now you just expanded your question with different things. Maybe don't jump into conclusions to early but instead provide (in a new question) more details about your problem first, like how "not working" exactly manifests and detailed packet captures from working and non-working things.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post on Stackoverflow.
Problem solved by NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy=NO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you have now determined that the problem is resolved by disabling the requirement for forward secrecy, I will leave my explanation regarding your original question of the unknown TLS versions.

**Original answer**

These are [GREASE](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-grease-01) values and are intended to weed out systems that don't correctly support unknown TLS versions.

It looks like it is doing its job and whatever filtering system(s) they have deployed has exactly the bug that GREASE is meant to find.

Unfortunately there is nothing you can on your side except try and report the problem to the providers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how does other applications such as Safari can not use this grease in TLS conversations?

Comment: @sbca68: Are you saying that going to the same URL with Safari on the same device as your app results in no errors?

Comment: yes, this URL works at the same time from Safari. But I make a wrong conclusion based on just Insomnia traffic dump. GREASE in supported version is not the reason of this problem - it contains in both App and Safari packet dumps. I have found another difference. See my update in original post.